# install brother wireless mcf-j625dw

Tags: scanner

I have installed the wireless printer on Ubuntu 20.04 but I can install the scanner despite I have downloaded the indicated driver
It demands the connection wireless but if the printer works I think also the scanner ?
Thanks for any help
Josef

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

- Go [here](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan) (main page), read and move on to [this page](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/) (Debian packages).
- Download and install `sane-airscan`.
- Execute `scanimage -L`. The output should give an entry beginning with `device airscan:...` . What ... is is shown to you.
- Check scanning with `"simple-scan airscan:.."`.
- Say whether you get the scanner to work and give the outputs of `scanimage -L` and `airscan-discover`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output
device `airscan:w1:Brother MFC-J625DW' is a WSD Brother MFC-J625DW ip=10.0.1.14

[devices]
Brother MFC-J625DW = http://10.0.1.14:80/WebServices/ScannerService, WSD
Thanks it is working well
Josef